# Geometry of an ellipse

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I was going through some properties a ellipses and this question comes to my mind:
Suppose you have an ellipse on paper with nothing marked on it and for some reason you need to find the foci. How can you do that with just a pencil and a compass?
Can we do that using this property: "The portion of a tangent to an ellipse between the point of contact and the directrix subtends a right angle at the corresponding focus." ?

Comment: Did you mean "just a pencil and a compass" or "just a ruler and a compass" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a ruler and compass construction, there is a nice sequence at http://whistleralley.com/conics/conic_construction/ellipse_parts/.  It shows how to find the center (via conjugate diameters), followed by the axes and then the foci.

Comment: oh thanks I get it now.